# What type of baking tray is WINGY?

Tags: baking

Could you tell me what is WINGY baking tray? It is used for baking pastry. The instruction reads: wingy/baton tray: 10/12 pieces.

Comment: Welcome to the site @Maja. A baton tray has long, narrow dips in it to hold pasties or rolls in a specific shape, but I've never heard of a wingy baton tray before. What is it you are trying to bake? If you could post a picture of what the end result is supposed to look like maybe we can help.

Comment: As an example, see http://www.mackies.com.au/bakery03_roll.htm ... batons are effectively for things shaped like hot dog dolls.

Answer (score 1):

All I've been able to find is that is a novelty name for a baton tray, this could be wrong but I've found no other tray called a "Wingy".

That or it could have been a typo in the recipe.